# Ngx datepicker showing days of previous month

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have some issue for the ngx date-picker calendar. The calendar show the days of the previous month. This is an example :

http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/16/rj9b.png
[image]

I have found the properties "selectFromOtherMonth" of the "BsDatepickerConfig" but it stil not working. Maybe I doing wrong...

Thank's for any help.

Comment: its not days from previous month, it is a number of week :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not days from previous month, it is a number of week.
You should use a `showWeekNumbers` property set to `false` to avoid this